# OPENvpn server traffic not use sshuttle

Tags: ubuntu, openvpn, ssh-tunnel

I have 2 server (server A and server B).
I installed Openvpn on server A and use OPENVPN CONNECT on my laptop and iphone (iOS) and all thing is ok.
now when i check my ip in laptop and iOS show SERVER A IP. good.

I installed sshuttle on server A and after run:

```
sshuttle --dns -D -r root@SERVER_B_IP
```

after entry password, now my ip in server A is SERVER B IP and all thing is fine.

when i use openvpn connect on pc or iOS but my ip still is SERVER A IP.
i need to all my traffic in laptop and iOS use server B (like server A after use sshuttle).

how i do this?

server a is ubuntu and server b is centos.
all configs (open vpn and sshuttle) is default.

Answer (score 0):

It might be late but try below command:
sshuttle -r root@Server-IP 0.0.0.0/0 --no-latency-control  --dns -D  --ns-hosts=1.1.1.1